# Show data in subsequent lines are increasing in size

Tags: python

My query is concerned with showing data in each line is larger than the previous line, i.e. Line 2 > Line 1, Line 3 > Line 2, where this would only occur up to the point where the data would have words, before restarting the 'iteration'.

The data set is as below

```
853764622753
1055334825425
927168311000
1142876772659
1390557034408
1538194473087
1567178619062
1459597906913
1345383143356
1204616439828
Australia
33050343783
48852482960
44291490421
52902703376
65951627200
69684317719
74164435946
75244166773
53074370486
37847715736
Azerbaijan
```

I have no clue what to do with the code. I understand that you would need to initialise a boolean to set as True. My end code should be able to process lines and give indication if *it is True or False* that the code has increased.

```
increased = True
    for x in open("dataset"):
        y = x.rstrip("\n")

        if y.isnumeric():
          floated = float(y)
          if increased = increased and (floated > floated ) ???CONFUSED
            print("GDP increased every year:",increased)
          else:
            print("GDP increased every year:",increased)
        else:
          str(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to keep a record of the previous line and compare the values. There's a couple of ways of doing this.

One simple way is like so

```
previous = None
increased = True
with open('dataset') as f:
    for line in f:
         line = line.strip()
         if not line:
              continue  # ignore blank lines
         if line.isnumeric():
              if previous is not None and increased:
                    # if increased is currently True, see if it is still True
                    increased = float(line) > float(previous)
              previous = line
         else:
              # Now prints out country name
              print('GDP for {} increased every year: {}'.format(line, increased))
              increased = True
              previous = None
```

Output from your example

```
GDP for Australia increased every year: False
GDP for Azerbaijan increased every year: False
```

Comment: True. but this also prints the print line alot of times?

Comment: GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True
GDP increased every year: True

Comment: It prints once for each country, which is want you want I assume. See my edit.

Comment: You need to repeat the logic at the end of the case where the last line(s) of the file is numeric rather than a country

Comment: @Chris_Rands The data looks like it has the data *before* the name of the country in the example.

Comment: Oh yah true, although odd